# RDP is not getting connected to AWS

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

[image: Error Image]

I was trying to connect RDP server from my Windows machine.

I am facing error that "The logon attempt failed"

I checked and found my Password is correct.

Earlier I connected rdp with "Administrator", now when I try to connect, the name is coming "LAPTOPNAME\Administrator" and I think this is causing the issue.

Please help me.

Comment: You are attempting to use an account that only exists on your laptop to authenticate a AWS instance.  That local account cannot be used in your current configuration.  You need to specify the correct machine name that the user exists on.

Comment: I have been connecting from same machine as I setup AWS from the same machine using "Administrator" as login id and "password". I believe machine name is correct. My username is "LAPTOPNAME\Administrator" now when I try to connect. Earlier I used only "Administrator". Can you guide me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect with the user `LAPTOPNAME\Administrator`. This user does not exist on your remote instance.

To connect as the remote administrator you should use the username `\Administrator`. The `\` indicates RDC should use the administrator account local to the remote instance. If this machine is part of a domain you might need to add the domain to front of the username `DOMAIN\Administrator`.

Comment: I am using AWS instance, say Public DNS (IPv4):
ec1-23-345-67-890.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com. So What do you think I can use before \Administrator..

Comment: You shouldn't need anything but you could try `ec1-23-345-67-890` or whatever you named your instance.